# Prove that the graph of a continuous function on $(-\infty, \infty)$ is completely determined once one knows a certain countable set of points on it.

Tags: real-analysis

A question from *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck:

> Prove that the graph of a continuous function on $(-\infty, \infty)$ is completely determined once one knows a certain countable set of points on it.

I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathbb Q$ is countable and dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: That's right! Thanks.